# Выдает ошибку при попытке создать новый HashMap в Яве

Tags: java, java-hashmap, hashmap

В классе Schedule имеется constructor

```
private  HashMap<DaysOfTheWeek, ArrayList<Program>> weeklyShedual;

public Schedule() {
    ArrayList<Program> daily = new ArrayList<>();
    weeklyShedual.put(DaysOfTheWeek.SUNDAY, daily);
    weeklyShedual.put(DaysOfTheWeek.MONDAY, daily);
    weeklyShedual.put(DaysOfTheWeek.TUESDAY, daily);
    weeklyShedual.put(DaysOfTheWeek.WEDNESDAY, daily);
    weeklyShedual.put(DaysOfTheWeek.THURSDAY, daily);
    weeklyShedual.put(DaysOfTheWeek.FRIDAY, daily);
    weeklyShedual.put(DaysOfTheWeek.SATURDAY, daily);
}
```

По идее он должен создать семь ключей по количеству дней недели (дни отдельно в Enum), и к каждому из них пустой ArrayList при команде

```
    Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
```

Но почему-то он выдаёт NullPointerException. Кто-то знает почему?

Comment: Может потому что Map == null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся фишка кроется в строке ->
`private  HashMap<DaysOfTheWeek, ArrayList<Program>> weeklyShedual;`
Это просто резервирование памяти для объекта `HashMap`, самого объекта там ещё нет
Чтобы не вылетала ошибка, должно быть что-то вроде 
`private  HashMap<DaysOfTheWeek, ArrayList<Program>> weeklyShedual = new HashMap<DaysOfTheWeek, ArrayList<Program>>();`

Comment: p.s. заранее намекну, что `daily` - это один и тот же объект, один список, и если нужно 7 пустых списков, каждый нужно создавать отдельно